# Array LinkedList Stacks

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

I have to use index 0 as the TOP of my stack and am having issues implementing this. I am getting all `null`s, but outputting 100, 200, and 300 are the only numbers I am getting. Is there something wrong with the implementation that I am overlooking? The push method is supposed to implement ArrayListStack that pushes the element at index 0, and should be able to only remove the top element (index 0)

```java
public class NaughtyArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E>
{
    private E[] data = (E[])(new Object[10]);
    private int size;
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (size == 0);
    }

    public void push(E newData)
    {
        if (size == data.length)
        {
            E[] newDataArray = (E[])(new Object[size*2]);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if(isEmpty())
                    data[0] = newData;
                else
                    newDataArray[i+1] = data[i];
            data = newDataArray;
        }

        data[0] = newData;
        size++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack<Pancake> breakfast = new NaughtyArrayStack<Pancake>();
        for (int i = 10; i <= 300; i += 10)
        {
            breakfast.push(new Pancake(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your `push` method does.

Comment: What is `data`? Share your full code

Comment: That requirement is like the worst performing implementation of a stack that I have ever seen. All stack add/remove operations are O(n).

Comment: Yes i know but we are forced to do pointlesss stuff like this, and then we get to run them to see the difference in time, and it if huge haha

Comment: So, let me try to understand the written code: When the `data` array is full, allocate new array (good), copy existing data to new array shifted by 1 (bad!), using weird `if` statement that can never be true (`isEmpty()` is false since size >= 10, so bad!), replace old array with new (good), then *replace* first element with new value (bad!), and update size (good). When `data` is not full, *replace* first element with new value (bad!), and update size (good).

Comment: Can you please format your code properly ? `else` from the `push` method is ambiguous. Moreover what does this sentence mean : ' I am getting all nulls, but outputting 100, 200 and 300 but are the only numbers I am getting.'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since someone else already gave you a full solution, here is a compact version, with no redundant code ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)):

```
public void push(E newValue)
{
    E[] newData = (this.size < this.data.length ? this.data : (E[])new Object[this.size * 2]);
    System.arraycopy(this.data, 0, newData, 1, this.size);
    newData[0] = newValue;
    this.data = newData;
    this.size++;
}
```

If you also add this method, you can print the stack without seeing any trailing null values:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder().append('[');
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
        if (i != 0) buf.append(", ");
        buf.append(this.data[i]);
    }
    return buf.append(']').toString();
}
```

Or the simpler version in Java 8:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
        joiner.add(String.valueOf(this.data[i]));
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the line

```
data[0] = newData;
```

you should be increment the index of data array but it is not done so the last value of every array over flow is only remaining.

Comment: thanks man that made it work, would you know why two nulls owuld be following

Answer (score 0):

Your push function is wrong. It should be something like this. When u push a new element you need to shift all the existing elements by 1 index otherwise you will just end up rewriting the index `0` and increment `size`. here is the code:

```
public void push(E newData) {
    if (size == data.length) {
        E[] newDataArray = (E[]) (new Object[size * 2]);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            newDataArray[i + 1] = data[i];
        }
        newDataArray[0] = newData; // set the top to the new element
        data = newDataArray; // set data to reference the bigger array
    } else {
        // shift all the elements int he array by one so that you can add the new element to the
        // index 0
        int i = size - 1;
        while (i >= 0) {
            data[i + 1] = data[i];
            i--;
        }
        data[0] = newData;
    }

    size++;
}
```

Comment: Why use a `while` loop? A `for` loop would be better, and it would likely have made you actually decrement `i`, which is needed to prevent **infinite loop**.

Comment: yeah sorry fixed the infinite loop problem. You can use either for or while loop. It doesn't matter. OP was missing this step of shifting the elements by 1.